# unity yield waitforsecond not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, yield

I am new in Unity developer, I start learning Unity with reading tutorials,demo,example, and video. And I have some trouble with use timer (like thread in unity, I guess it...), and here is my code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision colli){

    if (colli.collider.name == "Car") {
        Debug.Log("On Collision naz ~.~");
        Destroy(Car);    
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        GameObject clone = (GameObject) Instantiate(Bum, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        StartCoroutine(deleteObject(clone));
    // Just want to delete "clone" object after 1 second
    }
}

IEnumerator deleteObject(GameObject bum){
    Debug.Log("chuan bi destroy naz ~.~"); // <-- run normally
    yield return new  WaitForSeconds(1.0F);
    Debug.Log("Destroy rui naz =,='");    //  <-- not display
    Destroy (bum);
}
```

I do not know why ....

Comment: Is bum being destroyed? I'm asking because I am confused about yield statements in practice. If you swap the Debug.log() and the destroy statement, is the text displayed?

Comment: yes. the debug.log() after destroy statement is not running, I think the yield is not running too :(

Comment: yield WaitForSeconds(1) cause problem, need yeild retun new waitforsecond();

Comment: Why the yield statement is being used? isn't it only for interations? Or is it a unity thing?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ (maybe here people know unity better)

Comment: if we want to do something after some second. May be in other platform we use Thread.sleep(), I found in Unity we have to use yield WaitForSeconds(). I think so ... :D. if you know any solution other, let me show, thanks

Comment: Can't you just call Destroy(bum, 1.0f)? That will destroy the object after 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I found the solution. Because i am going to Destroy(this.gameObject) before starting the coroutine. A destroyed object cannot keep running a coroutine.
 change Destroy(this.gameObject) after Destroy(Bum) solve the problem :3